# Jenkins delivery pipeline view -how to add manual trigger(play button)?

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline, manual, delivery-pipeline

I am trying to connect/achieve below things:

- Pipeline having job with multiple **stages** and **tasks**
- Configure above pipeline with **[Delivery view plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/delivery-pipeline-plugin/)**
- Last task of last stage is to deploy to production [**caution**: want this task with manual trigger]

Jenkins version: 2.222.x

**Things I tried**

```
node {
  stage 'Build'
  task 'Compile'
  echo 'Compiling'
  sleep 1

  task 'Unit test'
  sleep 1

  stage 'Test'
  task 'Component tests'
  echo 'Running component tests'
  sleep 1

  task 'Integration tests'
  echo 'Running component tests'
  sleep 1

  stage 'Deploy'
  task 'Deploy to UAT'
  echo 'Deploy to UAT environment'
  sleep 1

  task 'Deploy to production'
  echo 'Deploy to production, but wanted with manual trigger'
  sleep 1
}
```

Below is the desired configuration which I am looking.
[desired configuration, delivery pipeline plugin wiki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN3pV.png)

I could able to achieve that manual trigger by creating multiple free style jobs with upstream and downstream configuration and for the manual step I can set post build job with manual trigger.
But that is something which I want in pipeline because there we have **task** (inside stage also we can do separate vertical tasks)feature.

Please help me and suggest how to achieve this.